# How to update the Foundry Templates when moving all the resources to another project/folder?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-templates

I have a template with all its artifacts in project `/ABC`. Now I want to move everything to project `/DEF`.

I can move it but how can I update all the dataset paths (input, output) inside the template code repository or the artifact of the template?

When I click the "New version" button in the template, all the artifacts' status is marked as "Removed".

[image]

I also tried to remove the `transforms-shrinkwrap.yml` and build the code repository again but I got this error:

```
Shrinkwrap could not be resolved due to the following errors: 
 - Alias '/ABC/input-dataset' does not exist.
     Known files that use this alias: [transforms-python/src/myproject/jobs/build_all.py]
```